# Print two or more inequality signs in the title of a plot

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

I wonder if anyone knows how to print two or more inequality signs in the title of a plot. Note that I do know how to print one inequality sign in the title. See the sample code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
basic.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
main <- substitute(alpha * " " !=  0)
plot <- basic.plot + ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(main))))
plot
```

This gives me a title of "alpha not equal to zero". However, I want my title to be "alpha not equal to beta not equal to zero". I tried the following but failed:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
basic.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
main <- substitute(alpha * " " != * beta * " " != 0)
plot <- basic.plot + ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(main))))
plot
```

Also note that I have experimented with a Unicode approach but failed as well:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
basic.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
main <- c("\u03B1 \u2260 \u03B2 \u2260 0")
plot <- basic.plot + ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(main))))
plot
```

[image: Unicode approach]

Comment: The unicode approach works for me.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks. I see. Any thoughts on mine? I edited the question and added a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe a matter of locale. Mine is `en_US.UTF-8`. You can check it with `Sys.getlocale()`.

Comment: @Pascal Yeah... I guess so too. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, carefully placing "" and using ~:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
basic.plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
main <- substitute(alpha ~ "" != "" ~beta ~ "" != ""~0)
plot <- basic.plot + ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(main))))
plot
```

[image]